# Colocar input al lado de otro

Tags: html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-3

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET y estoy creando un formulario, mi problema es que intento colocar un input al lado de otro como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo tengo asi
[image: Actual]

Al crear un proyecto en ASP.NET trae consigo la version de Bootstrap v3.4.1

Anexo mi codigo del formulario

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Registro", "Usuario", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <h4>Creacion de usuario.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NombreApellido, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NombreApellido, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fecha_Nacimiento, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fecha_Nacimiento, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", @Value = Model.Fecha_Nacimiento.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), id = "Fecha_Nacimiento" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telefono, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefono, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Direccion, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Direccion, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

}
```

Mi experencia es mas hacia el lado del back-end, si pueden guiarme se los agradeceria.

Gracias

Comment: Prueba cambiar esos `<div class="">` por `<div class="col-md-6">`

Comment: Si me funciono amigo, ahora debo jugar con el ya que el nombre de los input si es muy largo no se ajusta en la misma linea

Comment: Por ese motivo yo siempre dejo los label arriba del input

Comment: Probare el dia de mañana y le comento. ahorita saldre

Comment: Estuve realizando prueba y no hayo como colocarlo al lado sin que se corrompa el label, tendras alguna sugerencia aparte de colocarlo arriba